# Gulp prompt callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I can't seem to figure out how I wait for the setTimeout function to finish before task 'two' finishes.

The problem is that 'one' is executed before the callback of my prompt in 'two'.

```
gulp.task('test', ['one'])

gulp.task('one', ['two'], function(){
    gulputil.log("Starting one");
});

gulp.task('two', function(){
    gulputil.log("Starting two")
    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(prompt.prompt({
            type: 'checkbox',
            name: 'bump',
            message: 'What type of release is it? (Patch: hotfix, Minor: Release, Major: Major release)',
            choices: ['patch', 'minor', 'major']
        }, function(res){
            setTimeout(function(){
                gulputil.log("Starting prompt callback");               
            },200);
        }))
});
```

I've tried to add cb() to my function and call in within my prompt callback, but it results in a error message about cb being called too many times.

The only fix I've found is to change the prompt plugin to not call the cb and call the the cb on my own with an:

```
.on('end', function()){
    cb();
});
```

Am I missing something, or is there a bug in the prompt plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) because the tasks running parallel and the 2nd task don't knows when the first task has been finished.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to call your callback `callback` or `cb`?  If so, that's your problem - `.prompt` reuses those internally and overwrites yours (which needs to get to the setTimeout callback via closure).  Check out the source.

This works fine:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var prompt = require('gulp-prompt');
var gulputil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('test', ['one']);

gulp.task('one', ['two'], function(){
  gulputil.log("Starting one");
});

gulp.task('two', function(f){
 gulputil.log("Starting two");
 function f() { console.log( 'done' ); }
 return gulp.src('test.js')
   .pipe(prompt.prompt({
     type: 'checkbox',
     name: 'bump',
     message: 'What type of release is it? (Patch: hotfix, Minor: Release, Major: Major release)',
     choices: ['patch', 'minor', 'major']
   }, function(res){
              setTimeout(function(res){
                  gulputil.log("Starting prompt callback");
                  f();
               }, 200);               
    }));
})
```